# How can I submit .crash files manually?

Tags: bug-reporting

What process can I use to submit .crash files that aren't submitted to Ubuntu due to restrictions on my network?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_when_off-line) for further details about bug reporting. I copied and pasted the relevant info here for you.

First, gather the information about the target system in a file:

For a bug report about a system crash:

```
apport-cli -p <package name> --save bug.crash
```

For a bug report about any other issue:

```
apport-cli -f -p <package name> --save bug.apport
```

After copying it to a different system you can file that report using the following command:

```
ubuntu-bug -c <apport_file.extension>
```

If this is to be added to an existing bug report, also use the -u option:

```
ubuntu-bug -c <apport_file.extension> -u <bug number>
```

You will need to answer a few questions, and a web browser will be launched to complete the bug report.

Hope this helps!